# Xelatex bad encoding on output

Tags: xetex, pdf, font-encodings, xgreek

I'm using the 'xgreek' package and compiling the document with XeLaTeX (xetex); I can't find out why toc, date etc. seems corrupted (should be in greek)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine G}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}

some dummy text
ελληνικα 

\tableofcontents

\today

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance [image]

Comment: You are using miktex? xgreek.sty if faulty there. A bug report has already been made.

Comment: Is there any trick to solve it?

Comment: You need a correct sty, get xgreek.dtx and xgreek.ins from CTAN, put them in some tempory folder and then compile xgreek.ins with latex to get the .sty.

Comment: I overwitten the generated .sty over the old one, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

Ok I finally did It! I Just edited xgreek.sty [image]

Comment: This is not an answer, unless you tell *how* you changed `xgreek`.