# Strange symbols in xelatex

Tags: xetex, symbols

I use `xelatex` for my documents in greek language. When I type commands like `\today` or `\tableofcontents` I get these strange symbols.
[image]

My code is this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[amsbb]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\today
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

In my old computer or when I use `latex` everything works fine.

Comment: No problem here. Unrelated: remove the calls to `xunicode` and `xltxtra`. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274627/xelatex-bad-encoding-on-output But what happened is unknown; make sure your TeX distribution is up-to-date.

Comment: Do you know which input encoding your `.tex` file is using? That seems like it might make a difference.

Comment: @Arun. I think UTF-8

Comment: @egreg. I removed `xunicode` and `xltxtra` but nothing changed.

Comment: it looks like utf8 being interpreted as latin1, but since you use xetex which always uses utf8, I suspect that you xgreek package has been incorrectlly "double" encoded as utf8

Comment: I replaced the new xgreek.sty file with the old one from my other pc where it works but it didn't work.

Comment: If you comment out some of the lines, does it work? (I mean, does it no longer produce nonsense?)

Comment: @cfr. Yes the problem appears only when I use these commands and only in `xelatex`. It appears that there is an issue with `xgreek.sty` but I'm not sure.

Comment: The xgreek.sty in miktex is broken. There is already a bug report (https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2405/) but it hasn't been corrected yet.

Comment: I added some more info to the miktex bug report. It looks as if unpacking the ins with tex leads to the faulty sty.

Comment: Is this bug fixed now?