# \alph shows strange symbols when used with xgreek package

Tags: xetex, miktex, enumerate, texmaker, xgreek

I can assure you I searched a hell lot before posting this and I only post questions online if I have totally given up. :(

I am new in LaTeX since I chose it to write my undergraduate thesis. I can only write my thesis in Greek (since my professor doesn't want to bother forwarding my request to write it in English to the uni council -_- ). Our uni, University of Piraeus that is, recommends the Springer's monograph. So I downloaded the template and started working on it and soon I realized that I needed the **xgreek** package in order for the hyphenation to be automatic. The problem though is that in enumerate lists, the **\alph** and **\Alph** numeration style gets messed up when the **xgreek** package is used. An example:

[image]

The only code reffering to the enumerate list in the *svmono.cls* file is:

```
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii.}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\@alph\c@enumii}

\def\enumerate{%
\ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \ifx\setit@m\undefined
       \ifnum \@enumdepth=1 \leftmargini=\svitemindent
         \labelwidth\leftmargini\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
          \leftmarginii=\leftmargini \leftmarginiii=\leftmargini
       \fi
    \fi
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@enumctr\endcsname
        {\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
   \fi}
```

I figured out that the first 2 lines of that code get rid of the parentheses in the default style of the **\alph** numeration. The rest, I think it has to do with the width of the space before each nested list (?). I hope I make sense, I am trying my best to explain what I know in Greek with the vocabulary I know in English.

My preamble in the document is this as far:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{xgreek}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage{type1cm}

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}

\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Περίληψη}
\renewcommand{\ackname}{Ευχαριστίες}
\renewcommand{\andname}{και}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Βιβλιογραφία}
\renewcommand{\lastandname}{,και}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Παράρτημα}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Κεφάλαιο}
%\renewcommand{\claimname}{Claim}
%\renewcommand{\conjecturename}{Conjecture}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Περιεχόμενα}
%\renewcommand{\corollaryname}{Corollary}
\renewcommand{\definitionname}{Ορισμός}
\renewcommand{\emailname}{e-mail}
\renewcommand{\examplename}{Παράδειγμα}
\renewcommand{\exercisename}{Άσκηση}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Εικόνα}
\renewcommand{\forewordname}{Εισαγωγικό Σημείωμα}
\renewcommand{\keywordname}{{\bf Λέξεις κλειδιά:}}
%\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index}
%\renewcommand{\lemmaname}{Lemma}
%\renewcommand{\contriblistname}{List of Contributors}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Λίστα Εικόνων}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Λίστα Πινάκων}
%\renewcommand{\mailname}{{\it Correspondence to\/}:}
%\renewcommand{\noteaddname}{Note added in proof}
\renewcommand{\notename}{Σημείωση}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Μέρος}
\renewcommand{\prefacename}{Πρόλογος}
\renewcommand{\problemname}{Πρόβλημα}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Απόδειξη}
%\renewcommand{\propertyname}{Property}
\renewcommand{\propositionname}{Πρόταση}
\renewcommand{\questionname}{Ερώτηση}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Αναφορές}
\renewcommand{\remarkname}{Παρατήρηση}
\renewcommand{\seename}{βλέπε}
\renewcommand{\solutionname}{Λύση}
%\renewcommand{\subclassname}{{\it Subject Classifications\/}:}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Πίνακας}
\renewcommand{\theoremname}{Θεώρημα}

\makeindex
```

All those changes in the names work just fine even without the xgreek package but hyphenation does not work without it. (Some of them are commented out because I am not sure where they will be used in the document and I don't know what Greek word should replace them yet.)

Also, the date and some other parts appear incorrectly:
[image]

From what I understand, the use of **xgreek** replaces the English letters in the enumeration with the Greek ones. But then, and since I am building with **XeLaTeX**, why don't they appear correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you very much in advance!

Package, editor, compiler I am using and other system details:

- **MiKTeX 2.9**
- **Texmaker**
- **XeLaTeX**
- **Windows 7 Enterprise sp1**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The same problem appeared yesterday. I think that MiKTeX provides a garbled copy of `xgreek.sty`.

Comment: Thank you! So I guess I must find the correct copy of xgreek.sty? :/ Or try to correct the existing one? I found http://paketa.os.cs.teiath.gr/pub/tex/xetex/xgreek.sty online but when I turned it to utf-8 and tried to compile my document, I can see in the log that a control sequence (monotonic to be exact) is undefined. Now the repo sync does not work so I can't compare the old one with the one I found online so that I can see the differences between the two.. Oh well, I will keep on working on that.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not a MiKTeX user. I pinged Ulrike Fischer, who's the greatest expert in MiKTeX I know.

Comment: Welcome! To format code, simply press the `{}` button on top of the edit window.

Comment: You should, first of all, remove the calls to `mathptmx` and `type1cm`.

Comment: @egreg: It is a bug in xgreek.sty of miktex. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282036/strange-symbols-in-xelatex and https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2405/. It seems that using tex to unpack the dtx leads to the wrong output. Getting the ins and the dtx and using pdftex to unpack the sty should solve it.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: This is what I am trying to do now! From the link Tom gave me in his answer below i got the .dtx and .ins. But Texmaker has pdfLaTeX, not pdfTeX. Is this the same or not? :/ I will search further so that I can understand exactly how I should use those files to get the correct .sty and I hope I succeed! Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @ΦωτεινήΒέρδου: pdflatex should work too. Only the "old" tex fails. Simply put the ins and the dtx in some folder and then open the ins in your editor and compile it. Then open the created sty and check if it looks ok - if it contains greek chars it is fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I did! and everything worked fine! I also posted the solution to my question. :) Thank you again very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!! :D

In order to save the time and energy for other people that might face a similar problem with **xgreek.sty** of *MiKTeX*, I am proudly presenting the **CORRECT XGREEK.STY** file as the **pdftex.exe** produced it when I used it in command prompt on the **xgreek.ins** file.

```
%%
%% This is file `xgreek.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% xgreek.dtx  (with options: `xgreek')
%% 
%%  (c) Copyright 2007—2015 Apostolos Syropoulos
%%  This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the
%%  terms of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from
%%  http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt; either
%%  version 1.3c of the License, or any later version.
%% 
%%  This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%% 
%%  Please report errors or suggestions for improvement to
%% 
%%     Apostolos Syropoulos  (asyropoulos@yahoo.com)
%% 
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
\ProvidesFile{xgreek.sty}
 [2015/08/03 v2.61 Package `xgreek.sty']
\message{Package `xgreek' version 2.61 by Apostolos Syropoulos}
\global\lccode"0370="0371 \global\uccode"0370="0370
\global\lccode"0371="0371 \global\uccode"0371="0370
\global\lccode"0372="0373 \global\uccode"0372="0372
\global\lccode"0373="0373 \global\uccode"0373="0372
\global\lccode"0376="0377 \global\uccode"0376="0376
\global\lccode"0377="0377 \global\uccode"0377="0376
\global\lccode"03FD="037B \global\uccode"03FD="03FD
\global\lccode"037B="037B \global\uccode"037B="03FD
\global\lccode"03FE="037C \global\uccode"03FE="03FE
\global\lccode"037C="037C \global\uccode"037C="03FE
\global\lccode"03FF="037D \global\uccode"03FF="03FF
\global\lccode"037D="037D \global\uccode"037D="03FF
\global\lccode"0386="03AC \global\uccode"0386="0391
\global\lccode"0388="03AD \global\uccode"0388="0395
\global\lccode"0389="03AC \global\uccode"0389="0397
\global\lccode"038A="03AF \global\uccode"038A="0399
\global\lccode"038C="03CC \global\uccode"038C="039F
\global\lccode"038E="03CD \global\uccode"038E="03A5
\global\lccode"038F="03CE \global\uccode"038F="03A9
\global\lccode"0390="0390 \global\uccode"0390="03AA
\global\lccode"0391="03B1 \global\uccode"0391="0391
\global\lccode"0392="03B2 \global\uccode"0392="0392
\global\lccode"0393="03B3 \global\uccode"0393="0393
\global\lccode"0394="03B4 \global\uccode"0394="0394
\global\lccode"0395="03B5 \global\uccode"0395="0395
\global\lccode"0396="03B6 \global\uccode"0396="0396
\global\lccode"0397="03B7 \global\uccode"0397="0397
\global\lccode"0398="03B8 \global\uccode"0398="0398
\global\lccode"0399="03B9 \global\uccode"0399="0399
\global\lccode"039A="03BA \global\uccode"039A="039A
\global\lccode"039B="03BB \global\uccode"039B="039B
\global\lccode"039C="03BC \global\uccode"039C="039C
\global\lccode"039D="03BD \global\uccode"039D="039D
\global\lccode"039E="03BE \global\uccode"039E="039E
\global\lccode"039F="03BF \global\uccode"039F="039F
\global\lccode"03A0="03C0 \global\uccode"03A0="03A0
\global\lccode"03A1="03C1 \global\uccode"03A1="03A1
\global\lccode"03A3="03C3 \global\uccode"03A3="03A3
\global\lccode"03A4="03C4 \global\uccode"03A4="03A4
\global\lccode"03A5="03C5 \global\uccode"03A5="03A5
\global\lccode"03A6="03C6 \global\uccode"03A6="03A6
\global\lccode"03A7="03C7 \global\uccode"03A7="03A7
\global\lccode"03A8="03C8 \global\uccode"03A8="03A8
\global\lccode"03A9="03C9 \global\uccode"03A9="03A9
\global\lccode"03AA="03CA \global\uccode"03AA="03AA
\global\lccode"03AB="03CB \global\uccode"03AB="03AB
\global\lccode"03AC="03AC \global\uccode"03AC="0391
\global\lccode"03AD="03AD \global\uccode"03AD="0395
\global\lccode"03AE="03AE \global\uccode"03AE="0397
\global\lccode"03AF="03AF \global\uccode"03AF="0399
\global\lccode"03B0="03B0 \global\uccode"03B0="03AB
\global\lccode"03B1="03B1 \global\uccode"03B1="0391
\global\lccode"03B2="03B2 \global\uccode"03B2="0392
\global\lccode"03B3="03B3 \global\uccode"03B3="0393
\global\lccode"03B4="03B4 \global\uccode"03B4="0394
\global\lccode"03B5="03B5 \global\uccode"03B5="0395
\global\lccode"03B6="03B6 \global\uccode"03B6="0396
\global\lccode"03B7="03B7 \global\uccode"03B7="0397
\global\lccode"03B8="03B8 \global\uccode"03B8="0398
\global\lccode"03B9="03B9 \global\uccode"03B9="0399
\global\lccode"03BA="03BA \global\uccode"03BA="039A
\global\lccode"03BB="03BB \global\uccode"03BB="039B
\global\lccode"03BC="03BC \global\uccode"03BC="039C
\global\lccode"03BD="03BD \global\uccode"03BD="039D
\global\lccode"03BE="03BE \global\uccode"03BE="039E
\global\lccode"03BF="03BF \global\uccode"03BF="039F
\global\lccode"03C0="03C0 \global\uccode"03C0="03A0
\global\lccode"03C1="03C1 \global\uccode"03C1="03A1
\global\lccode"03C2="03C2 \global\uccode"03C2="03A3
\global\lccode"03C3="03C3 \global\uccode"03C3="03A3
\global\lccode"03C4="03C4 \global\uccode"03C4="03A4
\global\lccode"03C5="03C5 \global\uccode"03C5="03A5
\global\lccode"03C6="03C6 \global\uccode"03C6="03A6
\global\lccode"03C7="03C7 \global\uccode"03C7="03A7
\global\lccode"03C8="03C8 \global\uccode"03C8="03A8
\global\lccode"03C9="03C9 \global\uccode"03C9="03A9
\global\lccode"03CA="03CA \global\uccode"03CA="03AA
\global\lccode"03CB="03CB \global\uccode"03CB="03AB
\global\lccode"03CC="03CC \global\uccode"03CC="039F
\global\lccode"03CD="03CD \global\uccode"03CD="03A5
\global\lccode"03CE="03CE \global\uccode"03CE="03A9
\global\lccode"03D0="03D0 \global\uccode"03D0="0392
\global\lccode"03D1="03D1 \global\uccode"03D1="0398
\global\lccode"03D2="03C5 \global\uccode"03D2="03A5
\global\lccode"03D3="03CD \global\uccode"03D3="03A5
\global\lccode"03D4="03CB \global\uccode"03D4="03AB
\global\lccode"03D5="03C6 \global\uccode"03D5="03A6
\global\lccode"03D6="03C0 \global\uccode"03D6="03A0
\global\lccode"03DA="03DB \global\uccode"03DA="03DA
\global\lccode"03DB="03DB \global\uccode"03DB="03DA
\global\lccode"03DC="03DD \global\uccode"03DC="03DC
\global\lccode"03DD="03DD \global\uccode"03DD="03DC
\global\lccode"03DE="03DF \global\uccode"03DE="03DE
\global\lccode"03DF="03DF \global\uccode"03DF="03DE
\global\lccode"03E0="03E1 \global\uccode"03E0="03E0
\global\lccode"03E1="03E1 \global\uccode"03E1="03E0
\global\lccode"03F0="03BA \global\uccode"03F0="039A
\global\lccode"03F1="03C1 \global\uccode"03F1="03A1
\global\lccode"03F2="03F2 \global\uccode"03F2="03F9
\global\lccode"03F9="03F2 \global\uccode"03F9="03F9
\global\lccode"1F00="1F00 \global\uccode"1F00="0391
\global\lccode"1F01="1F01 \global\uccode"1F01="0391
\global\lccode"1F02="1F02 \global\uccode"1F02="0391
\global\lccode"1F03="1F03 \global\uccode"1F03="0391
\global\lccode"1F04="1F04 \global\uccode"1F04="0391
\global\lccode"1F05="1F05 \global\uccode"1F05="0391
\global\lccode"1F06="1F06 \global\uccode"1F06="0391
\global\lccode"1F07="1F07 \global\uccode"1F07="0391
\global\lccode"1F08="1F00 \global\uccode"1F08="0391
\global\lccode"1F09="1F01 \global\uccode"1F09="0391
\global\lccode"1F0A="1F02 \global\uccode"1F0A="0391
\global\lccode"1F0B="1F03 \global\uccode"1F0B="0391
\global\lccode"1F0C="1F04 \global\uccode"1F0C="0391
\global\lccode"1F0D="1F05 \global\uccode"1F0D="0391
\global\lccode"1F0E="1F06 \global\uccode"1F0E="0391
\global\lccode"1F0F="1F07 \global\uccode"1F0F="0391
\global\lccode"1F10="1F10 \global\uccode"1F10="0395
\global\lccode"1F11="1F11 \global\uccode"1F11="0395
\global\lccode"1F12="1F12 \global\uccode"1F12="0395
\global\lccode"1F13="1F13 \global\uccode"1F13="0395
\global\lccode"1F14="1F14 \global\uccode"1F14="0395
\global\lccode"1F15="1F15 \global\uccode"1F15="0395
\global\lccode"1F18="1F10 \global\uccode"1F18="0395
\global\lccode"1F19="1F11 \global\uccode"1F19="0395
\global\lccode"1F1A="1F12 \global\uccode"1F1A="0395
\global\lccode"1F1B="1F13 \global\uccode"1F1B="0395
\global\lccode"1F1C="1F14 \global\uccode"1F1C="0395
\global\lccode"1F1D="1F15 \global\uccode"1F1D="0395
\global\lccode"1F20="1F20 \global\uccode"1F20="0397
\global\lccode"1F21="1F21 \global\uccode"1F21="0397
\global\lccode"1F22="1F22 \global\uccode"1F22="0397
\global\lccode"1F23="1F23 \global\uccode"1F23="0397
\global\lccode"1F24="1F24 \global\uccode"1F24="0397
\global\lccode"1F25="1F25 \global\uccode"1F25="0397
\global\lccode"1F26="1F26 \global\uccode"1F26="0397
\global\lccode"1F27="1F27 \global\uccode"1F27="0397
\global\lccode"1F28="1F20 \global\uccode"1F28="0397
\global\lccode"1F29="1F21 \global\uccode"1F29="0397
\global\lccode"1F2A="1F22 \global\uccode"1F2A="0397
\global\lccode"1F2B="1F23 \global\uccode"1F2B="0397
\global\lccode"1F2C="1F24 \global\uccode"1F2C="0397
\global\lccode"1F2D="1F25 \global\uccode"1F2D="0397
\global\lccode"1F2E="1F26 \global\uccode"1F2E="0397
\global\lccode"1F2F="1F27 \global\uccode"1F2F="0397
\global\lccode"1F30="1F30 \global\uccode"1F30="0399
\global\lccode"1F31="1F31 \global\uccode"1F31="0399
\global\lccode"1F32="1F32 \global\uccode"1F32="0399
\global\lccode"1F33="1F33 \global\uccode"1F33="0399
\global\lccode"1F34="1F34 \global\uccode"1F34="0399
\global\lccode"1F35="1F35 \global\uccode"1F35="0399
\global\lccode"1F36="1F36 \global\uccode"1F36="0399
\global\lccode"1F37="1F37 \global\uccode"1F37="0399
\global\lccode"1F38="1F30 \global\uccode"1F38="0399
\global\lccode"1F39="1F31 \global\uccode"1F39="0399
\global\lccode"1F3A="1F32 \global\uccode"1F3A="0399
\global\lccode"1F3B="1F33 \global\uccode"1F3B="0399
\global\lccode"1F3C="1F34 \global\uccode"1F3C="0399
\global\lccode"1F3D="1F35 \global\uccode"1F3D="0399
\global\lccode"1F3E="1F36 \global\uccode"1F3E="0399
\global\lccode"1F3F="1F37 \global\uccode"1F3F="0399
\global\lccode"1F40="1F40 \global\uccode"1F40="039F
\global\lccode"1F41="1F41 \global\uccode"1F41="039F
\global\lccode"1F42="1F42 \global\uccode"1F42="039F
\global\lccode"1F43="1F43 \global\uccode"1F43="039F
\global\lccode"1F44="1F44 \global\uccode"1F44="039F
\global\lccode"1F45="1F45 \global\uccode"1F45="039F
\global\lccode"1F48="1F40 \global\uccode"1F48="039F
\global\lccode"1F49="1F41 \global\uccode"1F49="039F
\global\lccode"1F4A="1F42 \global\uccode"1F4A="039F
\global\lccode"1F4B="1F43 \global\uccode"1F4B="039F
\global\lccode"1F4C="1F44 \global\uccode"1F4C="039F
\global\lccode"1F4D="1F45 \global\uccode"1F4D="039F
\global\lccode"1F50="1F50 \global\uccode"1F50="03A5
\global\lccode"1F51="1F51 \global\uccode"1F51="03A5
\global\lccode"1F52="1F52 \global\uccode"1F52="03A5
\global\lccode"1F53="1F53 \global\uccode"1F53="03A5
\global\lccode"1F54="1F54 \global\uccode"1F54="03A5
\global\lccode"1F55="1F55 \global\uccode"1F55="03A5
\global\lccode"1F56="1F56 \global\uccode"1F56="03A5
\global\lccode"1F57="1F57 \global\uccode"1F57="03A5
\global\lccode"1F59="1F51 \global\uccode"1F59="03A5
\global\lccode"1F5B="1F53 \global\uccode"1F5B="03A5
\global\lccode"1F5D="1F55 \global\uccode"1F5D="03A5
\global\lccode"1F5F="1F57 \global\uccode"1F5F="03A5
\global\lccode"1F60="1F60 \global\uccode"1F60="03A9
\global\lccode"1F61="1F61 \global\uccode"1F61="03A9
\global\lccode"1F62="1F62 \global\uccode"1F62="03A9
\global\lccode"1F63="1F63 \global\uccode"1F63="03A9
\global\lccode"1F64="1F64 \global\uccode"1F64="03A9
\global\lccode"1F65="1F65 \global\uccode"1F65="03A9
\global\lccode"1F66="1F66 \global\uccode"1F66="03A9
\global\lccode"1F67="1F67 \global\uccode"1F67="03A9
\global\lccode"1F68="1F60 \global\uccode"1F68="03A9
\global\lccode"1F69="1F61 \global\uccode"1F69="03A9
\global\lccode"1F6A="1F62 \global\uccode"1F6A="03A9
\global\lccode"1F6B="1F63 \global\uccode"1F6B="03A9
\global\lccode"1F6C="1F64 \global\uccode"1F6C="03A9
\global\lccode"1F6D="1F65 \global\uccode"1F6D="03A9
\global\lccode"1F6E="1F66 \global\uccode"1F6E="03A9
\global\lccode"1F6F="1F67 \global\uccode"1F6F="03A9
\global\lccode"1F70="1F70 \global\uccode"1F70="0391
\global\lccode"1F71="1F71 \global\uccode"1F71="0391
\global\lccode"1F72="1F72 \global\uccode"1F72="0395
\global\lccode"1F73="1F73 \global\uccode"1F73="0395
\global\lccode"1F74="1F74 \global\uccode"1F74="0397
\global\lccode"1F75="1F75 \global\uccode"1F75="0397
\global\lccode"1F76="1F76 \global\uccode"1F76="0399
\global\lccode"1F77="1F77 \global\uccode"1F77="0399
\global\lccode"1F78="1F78 \global\uccode"1F78="039F
\global\lccode"1F79="1F79 \global\uccode"1F79="039F
\global\lccode"1F7A="1F7A \global\uccode"1F7A="03A5
\global\lccode"1F7B="1F7B \global\uccode"1F7B="03A5
\global\lccode"1F7C="1F7C \global\uccode"1F7C="03A9
\global\lccode"1F7D="1F7D \global\uccode"1F7D="03A9
\global\lccode"1F80="1F80 \global\uccode"1F80="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F81="1F81 \global\uccode"1F81="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F82="1F82 \global\uccode"1F82="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F83="1F83 \global\uccode"1F83="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F84="1F84 \global\uccode"1F84="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F85="1F85 \global\uccode"1F85="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F86="1F86 \global\uccode"1F86="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F87="1F87 \global\uccode"1F87="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F88="1F80 \global\uccode"1F88="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F89="1F81 \global\uccode"1F89="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F8A="1F82 \global\uccode"1F8A="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F8B="1F83 \global\uccode"1F8B="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F8C="1F84 \global\uccode"1F8C="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F8D="1F85 \global\uccode"1F8D="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F8E="1F86 \global\uccode"1F8E="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F8F="1F87 \global\uccode"1F8F="1FBC
\global\lccode"1F90="1F90 \global\uccode"1F90="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F91="1F91 \global\uccode"1F91="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F92="1F92 \global\uccode"1F92="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F93="1F93 \global\uccode"1F93="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F94="1F94 \global\uccode"1F94="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F95="1F95 \global\uccode"1F95="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F96="1F96 \global\uccode"1F96="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F97="1F97 \global\uccode"1F97="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F98="1F90 \global\uccode"1F98="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F99="1F91 \global\uccode"1F99="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F9A="1F92 \global\uccode"1F9A="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F9B="1F93 \global\uccode"1F9B="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F9C="1F94 \global\uccode"1F9C="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F9D="1F95 \global\uccode"1F9D="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F9E="1F96 \global\uccode"1F9E="1FCC
\global\lccode"1F9F="1F97 \global\uccode"1F9F="1FCC
\global\lccode"1FA0="1FA0 \global\uccode"1FA0="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FA1="1FA1 \global\uccode"1FA1="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FA2="1FA2 \global\uccode"1FA2="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FA3="1FA3 \global\uccode"1FA3="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FA4="1FA4 \global\uccode"1FA4="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FA5="1FA5 \global\uccode"1FA5="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FA6="1FA6 \global\uccode"1FA6="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FA7="1FA7 \global\uccode"1FA7="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FA8="1FA0 \global\uccode"1FA8="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FA9="1FA1 \global\uccode"1FA9="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FAA="1FA2 \global\uccode"1FAA="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FAB="1FA3 \global\uccode"1FAB="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FAC="1FA4 \global\uccode"1FAC="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FAD="1FA5 \global\uccode"1FAD="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FAE="1FA6 \global\uccode"1FAE="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FAF="1FA7 \global\uccode"1FAF="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FB0="1FB0 \global\uccode"1FB0="1FB8
\global\lccode"1FB1="1FB1 \global\uccode"1FB1="1FB9
\global\lccode"1FB2="1FB2 \global\uccode"1FB2="1FBC
\global\lccode"1FB3="1FB3 \global\uccode"1FB3="1FBC
\global\lccode"1FB4="1FB4 \global\uccode"1FB4="1FBC
\global\lccode"1FB6="1FB6 \global\uccode"1FB6="0391
\global\lccode"1FB7="1FB7 \global\uccode"1FB7="1FBC
\global\lccode"1FB8="1FB0 \global\uccode"1FB8="1FB8
\global\lccode"1FB9="1FB1 \global\uccode"1FB9="1FB9
\global\lccode"1FBA="1F70 \global\uccode"1FBA="0391
\global\lccode"1FBB="1F71 \global\uccode"1FBB="0391
\global\lccode"1FBC="1FB3 \global\uccode"1FBC="1FBC
\global\lccode"1FBD="1FBD \global\uccode"1FBD="1FBD
\global\lccode"1FC2="1FC2 \global\uccode"1FC2="1FCC
\global\lccode"1FC3="1FC3 \global\uccode"1FC3="1FCC
\global\lccode"1FC4="1FC4 \global\uccode"1FC4="1FCC
\global\lccode"1FC6="1FC6 \global\uccode"1FC6="0397
\global\lccode"1FC7="1FC7 \global\uccode"1FC7="1FCC
\global\lccode"1FC8="1F72 \global\uccode"1FC8="0395
\global\lccode"1FC9="1F73 \global\uccode"1FC9="0395
\global\lccode"1FCA="1F74 \global\uccode"1FCA="0397
\global\lccode"1FCB="1F75 \global\uccode"1FCB="0397
\global\lccode"1FCC="1FC3 \global\uccode"1FCC="1FCC
\global\lccode"1FD0="1FD0 \global\uccode"1FD0="1FD8
\global\lccode"1FD1="1FD1 \global\uccode"1FD1="1FD9
\global\lccode"1FD2="1FD2 \global\uccode"1FD2="03AA
\global\lccode"1FD3="1FD3 \global\uccode"1FD3="03AA
\global\lccode"1FD6="1FD6 \global\uccode"1FD6="0399
\global\lccode"1FD7="1FD7 \global\uccode"1FD7="03AA
\global\lccode"1FD8="1FD0 \global\uccode"1FD8="1FD8
\global\lccode"1FD9="1FD1 \global\uccode"1FD9="1FD9
\global\lccode"1FDA="1F76 \global\uccode"1FDA="0399
\global\lccode"1FDB="1F77 \global\uccode"1FDB="0399
\global\lccode"1FE0="1FE0 \global\uccode"1FE0="1FE8
\global\lccode"1FE1="1FE1 \global\uccode"1FE1="1FE9
\global\lccode"1FE2="1FE2 \global\uccode"1FE2="03AB
\global\lccode"1FE3="1FE3 \global\uccode"1FE3="03AB
\global\lccode"1FE4="1FE4 \global\uccode"1FE4="03A1
\global\lccode"1FE5="1FE5 \global\uccode"1FE5="03A1
\global\lccode"1FE6="1FE6 \global\uccode"1FE6="03A5
\global\lccode"1FE7="1FE7 \global\uccode"1FE7="03AB
\global\lccode"1FE8="1FE0 \global\uccode"1FE8="1FE8
\global\lccode"1FE9="1FE1 \global\uccode"1FE9="1FE9
\global\lccode"1FEA="1F7A \global\uccode"1FEA="03A5
\global\lccode"1FEB="1F7B \global\uccode"1FEB="03A5
\global\lccode"1FEC="1FE5 \global\uccode"1FEC="1FEC
\global\lccode"1FF2="1FF2 \global\uccode"1FF2="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FF3="1FF3 \global\uccode"1FF3="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FF4="1FF4 \global\uccode"1FF4="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FF6="1FF6 \global\uccode"1FF6="03A9
\global\lccode"1FF7="1FF7 \global\uccode"1FF7="1FFC
\global\lccode"1FF8="1F78 \global\uccode"1FF8="039F
\global\lccode"1FF9="1F79 \global\uccode"1FF9="039F
\global\lccode"1FFA="1F7C \global\uccode"1FFA="03A9
\global\lccode"1FFB="1F7D \global\uccode"1FFB="03A9
\global\lccode"1FFC="1FF3 \global\uccode"1FFC="1FFC
\def\prefacename{Πρόλογος}%
\def\refname{Αναφορές}%
\def\abstractname{Περίληψη}%
\def\bibname{Βιβλιογραφία}%
\def\chaptername{Κεφάλαιο}%
\def\appendixname{Παράρτημα}%
\def\contentsname{Περιεχόμενα}%
\def\listfigurename{Κατάλογος σχημάτων}%
\def\listtablename{Κατάλογος πινάκων}%
\def\indexname{Ευρετήριο}%
\def\figurename{Σχήμα}%
\def\tablename{Πίνακας}%
\def\partname{Μέρος}%
\def\enclname{Συνημμένα}%
\def\ccname{Κοινοποίηση}%
\def\headtoname{Προς}%
\def\pagename{Σελίδα}%
\def\seename{βλέπε}%
\def\alsoname{βλέπε επίσης}%
\def\proofname{Απόδειξη}%
\def\glossaryname{Γλωσσάρι}%
\def\polytonicn@mes{%
  \def\refname{Ἀναφορὲς}%
  \def\indexname{Εὑρετήριο}%
  \def\figurename{Σχῆμα}%
  \def\headtoname{Πρὸς}%
  \def\alsoname{βλέπε ἐπίσης}%
  \def\proofname{Ἀπόδειξη}%
}
\def\@ncientn@mes{%
  \def\prefacename{Προοίμιον}%
  \def\abstractname{Περίληψις}%
  \def\bibname{Βιβλιογραφία}%
  \def\chaptername{Κεφάλαιον}%
  \def\appendixname{Παράρτημα}%
  \def\contentsname{Περιεχόμενα}%
  \def\listfigurename{Κατάλογος σχημάτων}%
  \def\listtablename{Κατάλογος πινάκων}%
  \def\indexname{Εὑρετήριον}%
  \def\tablename{Πίναξ}%
  \def\partname{Μέρος}%
  \def\enclname{Συνημμένως}%
  \def\ccname{Κοινοποίησις}%
  \def\headtoname{Πρὸς}%
  \def\pagename{Σελὶς}%
  \def\seename{ὃρα}%
  \def\alsoname{ὃρα ὡσαύτως}%
  \def\proofname{Ἀπόδειξις}%
  \def\glossaryname{Γλωσσάριον}%
  \def\refname{Ἀναφοραὶ}%
  \def\figurename{Σχῆμα}%
  \def\headtoname{Πρὸς}%
}
\def\gr@month{%
  \ifcase\month\or Ιανουαρίου\or Φεβρουαρίου\or Μαρτίου\or Απριλίου\or
    Μαΐου\or Ιουνίου\or Ιουλίου\or Αυγούστου\or
     Σεπτεμβρίου\or Οκτωβρίου\or Νοεμβρίου\or Δεκεμβρίου\fi}
\def\today{\number\day \space \gr@month\space \number\year}
\def\gr@c@month{%
  \ifcase\month\or Ἰανουαρίου\or Φεβρουαρίου\or Μαρτίου\or Ἀπριλίου\or
   Μαΐου\or Ἰουνίου\or Ἰουλίου\or Αὐγούστου\or Σεπτεμβρίου\or
  Ὀκτωβρίου\or Νοεμβρίου\or Δεκεμβρίου\fi}
\def\anwtonos{ʹ} %GREEK NUMERAl SIGN
\let\numer@lsign\anwtonos
\def\katwtonos{͵} %GREEK LOWER NUMERAL SIGN
\def\koppa{\char"03DF\relax}
\def\sampi{\char"03E1\relax}
\def\Digamma{\char"03DC\relax}
\def\ddigamma{\char"03DD\relax}
\def\anoteleia{\char"0387\relax}
\def\euro{\char"20AC\relax}
\def\permill{\char"2030\relax}
\def\stigma{στ\relax}
\frenchspacing
\let\@saveafterindentfalse\@afterindentfalse
\let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
\@afterindenttrue
\DeclareOption{monogreek}{%
   \language\l@monogreek%
}
\DeclareOption{polygreek}{%
   \language\l@polygreek%
   \polytonicn@mes%
   \let\gr@month\gr@c@month%
}
\DeclareOption{ancientgreek}{%
   \language\l@ancientgreek%
   \@ncientn@mes%
   \let\gr@month\gr@c@month%
}
\DeclareOption{stigma}{%
   \def\stigma{\char"03DA\relax}
}
\DeclareOption{noindentfirst}{%
   \let\@afterindentfalse\@saveafterindentfalse
}
\DeclareOption{nonumeralsign}{%
   \let\numer@lsign\relax
}
\ExecuteOptions{monogreek}
\ProcessOptions
\def\gr@ill@value#1{%
  \PackageWarning{xgreek}{Illegal value (#1) for greeknumeral}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\anw@false{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\anw@print{}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\anw@true{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\anw@print{\numer@lsign}}
\anw@true
\def\@greeknumeral#1{%
  \ifnum#1<\@ne\space\gr@ill@value{#1}%
  \else
    \ifnum#1<10\expandafter\gr@num@i\number#1%
    \else
      \ifnum#1<100\expandafter\gr@num@ii\number#1%
      \else
        \ifnum#1<\@m\expandafter\gr@num@iii\number#1%
        \else
          \ifnum#1<\@M\expandafter\gr@num@iv\number#1%
          \else
            \ifnum#1<100000\expandafter\gr@num@v\number#1%
            \else
              \ifnum#1<1000000\expandafter\gr@num@vi\number#1%
              \else
                \space\gr@ill@value{#1}%
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\gr@num@i#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or α\or β\or γ\or δ\or ε\or \stigma\or ζ\or η\or θ\fi
  \ifnum#1=\z@\else\anw@true\fi\anw@print}
\def\gr@num@ii#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or ι\or κ\or λ\or μ\or ν\or ξ\or ο\or π\or \koppa\fi
  \ifnum#1=\z@\else\anw@true\fi\gr@num@i}
\def\gr@num@iii#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or ρ\or σ\or τ\or υ\or φ\or χ\or ψ\or ω\or \sampi\fi
  \ifnum#1=\z@\anw@false\else\anw@true\fi\gr@num@ii}
\def\gr@num@iv#1{%
  \ifnum#1=\z@\else\katwtonos\fi
  \ifcase#1\or α\or β\or γ\or δ\or ε\or \stigma\or ζ\or η\or θ\fi
  \gr@num@iii}
\def\gr@num@v#1{%
  \ifnum#1=\z@\else\katwtonos\fi
  \ifcase#1\or ι\or κ\or λ\or μ\or ν\or ξ\or ο\or π\or \koppa\fi
  \gr@num@iv}
\def\gr@num@vi#1{%
  \katwtonos
  \ifcase#1\or ρ\or σ\or τ\or υ\or φ\or χ\or ψ\or ω\or \sampi\fi
  \gr@num@v}
\def\@Greeknumeral#1{%
  \expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\@greeknumeral{#1}}}
\def\greeknumeral#1{%
  \let\@numer@lsign\numer@lsign%
  \let\numer@lsign\anwtonos%
  \@greeknumeral{#1}
  \let\numer@lsign\@numer@lsign}
\def\Greeknumeral#1{%
  \let\@numer@lsign\numer@lsign%
  \let\numer@lsign\anwtonos%
  \@Greeknumeral{#1}
  \let\numer@lsign\@numer@lsign}
\newcount\@attic@num
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\@@atticnum}[1]{%
        \@attic@num#1\relax
        \ifnum\@attic@num<\@ne%
          \space%
          \PackageWarning{xgreek}{%
          Illegal value (\the\@attic@num) for acrophonic Attic numeral}%
        \else\ifnum\@attic@num>249999%
          \space%
          \PackageWarning{xgreek}{%
          Value too large (\the\@attic@num) for acrophonic Attic numeral}%
        \else
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>49999\do{%
               ^^^^^10147\advance\@attic@num-50000}%
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>9999\do{%
               M\advance\@attic@num-\@M}%
            \ifnum\@attic@num>4999%
               ^^^^^10146\advance\@attic@num-5000%
            \fi\relax
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>999\do{%
               Χ\advance\@attic@num-\@m}%
            \ifnum\@attic@num>499%
               ^^^^^10145\advance\@attic@num-500%
            \fi\relax
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>99\do{%
               Η\advance\@attic@num-100}%
            \ifnum\@attic@num>49%
               ^^^^^10144\advance\@attic@num-50%
            \fi\relax
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>9\do{%
               Δ\advance\@attic@num by-10}%
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>4\do{%
               Π\advance\@attic@num-5}%
            \ifcase\@attic@num\or Ι\or ΙΙ\or ΙΙΙ\or ΙΙΙΙ\fi%
   \fi\fi}
\def\@atticnum#1{%
     \expandafter\@@atticnum\expandafter{\the#1}}
\def\atticnum#1{%
     \@attic@num#1\relax
     \@atticnum{\@attic@num}}
\let\latin@alph\@alph
\let\latin@Alph\@Alph
\def\greek@alph#1{\expandafter\@greeknumeral\expandafter{\the#1}}
\def\greek@Alph#1{\expandafter\@Greeknumeral\expandafter{\the#1}}
  \let\@alph\greek@alph
  \let\@Alph\greek@Alph
\def\nogreekalph{%
  \let\@alph\latin@alph
  \let\@Alph\latin@Alph}
\def\greekalph{%
  \let\@alph\greek@alph
  \let\@Alph\greek@Alph}
\def\setlanguage#1{%
   \expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\relax%
   \typeout{^^J Error: No hyphenation pattern for language #1 loaded,}%
   \typeout{ default hyphenation patterns are used.^^J}%
   \language=0%
   \else\language=\csname l@#1\endcsname\fi}
\def\grtoday{%
  \expandafter\greeknumeral\expandafter{\the\day}\space
  \gr@c@month\space
  \expandafter\greeknumeral\expandafter{\the\year}}
\def\Grtoday{%
  \expandafter\Greeknumeral\expandafter{\the\day}\space
  \gr@c@month\space
  \expandafter\Greeknumeral\expandafter{\the\year}}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `xgreek.sty'.
```

Keep in mind to paste it in Notepad++ and the options on the bottom to be Dos\Windows and UTF-8. Then replace the old **xgreek.sty** with the new one in file *MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xgreek* wherever your *MiKTeX* was installed. It works only with *XeLaTeX* compiler of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

May it is worth to look inside the package documentation. For xgreek you can find it [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xgreek?lang=de) and for enumerate in the comments. I also find the enumitem package which may can help you. With this package you can add an optional field to the enumerate environment. So you may can try

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*]

\item item a

\item item b

\end{enumerate}
```

You can also change it global in your preamble with `\setenumerate[0]{label=(\Alph*)}`

The latter example changes the character for the whole document, with the former example you can change it individually for each list.

I hope that this is what you wanted.

Comment: enumerate package [link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumerate?lang=de)

Comment: enumitem package [link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=de)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is about corrupted utf8 strings generated by the package.

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this question because I do have a similar issue. In my case the letters of the list are in Greek and I want them in English. I found out that I could use the next (not robust) code:

```
\begin{description}[font=\mdseries]
\item[a] item a
\item[b] item b
\end{description}
```

with the `enumitem` package and the `xgreek` one.